# using phone camera with wap

Tags: mobile, camera, wap

I going to create a wap site using wml and servlets, it should be able to access phones camera and take a snapshot. Is it possible to a wap site to access phones camera?

I know it is not possible in straightforward way, since wap sites are running under lots of restrictions in a mobile. But is there any way to get around these restrictions and use the phones camera?

Thanks in advance,
Nuwan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think WAP is able to access any of the hardware of a phone. Perhaps some phones expose camera functionality via J2ME (or in the case of iPhones/Android/Windows Mobile, an OS specific API).

This is why many sites ask you to email/MMS in your photos to upload them.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. I have another question related to this if you don't mind. Would it be possible to create a mail using a wap system?, because if I can initiate the mailer of the camera, I can attach a picture and send to the server. Would it be possible thing to do?

Comment: On the phone I think the best you can do with WML is to create a HTML style mailto link, which just spawns a new mail, and fills in it, but requires the user to attach a photo to it and press Send: http://www.blackberryforums.com/rim-software/1277-browser-support-issue-mailto.html looks like the support for mailto links is not 100% either http://www.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?p=42616